# scala constrain type of list objects by object property type

Tags: scala, generics, scala-collections, implicit

Assuming a class like this:

```
sealed trait ParentTrait
sealed trait Trait1 extends ParentTrait
sealed trait Trait2 extends ParentTrait
...
case object O1 extends extends Trait1
case object O2 extends extends Trait1
....
....
case object Oi extends Trait2
case object Oj extends Trait2

case class A {
   ... fields ...
   val someField: ParentTrait 
}
```

How can I constrain a function to receive objects of `A` with `someField` of type `Trait2`?

i.e.

```
def myFunction(seq : Seq[A where A.someField is a Trait2] = {
  here each item.someField in seq is a Trait2 type
}
```

Comment: Did you try ```def myFunction(seq : Seq[{val someField: Trait2}])```?

Comment: i don't understand - How is seq a list of A's?

Comment: Ah, I see. Then you might try ```def myFunction(seq : Seq[A with {val someField: Trait2}])```

Answer (score 1):

I might misunderstand the question somehow, but if you would like to constrain a function to receive case classes that contain only certain element types, the following would do:

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

sealed trait ParentTrait
sealed trait Trait1 extends ParentTrait
sealed trait Trait2 extends ParentTrait

case object O1 extends Trait1
case object O2 extends Trait1

case object Oi extends Trait2
case object Oj extends Trait2

case class A[PT <: ParentTrait](someField: PT)

def myfunc[PT <: ParentTrait](seq: Seq[A[PT]]) : Unit = ???

val st1: Seq[A[Trait1]] = Seq(A(O1), A(O2))
val st2: Seq[A[Trait2]] = Seq(A(Oi), A(Oj))

myfunc[Trait2](st2)
myfunc[Trait2](st1)

// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

<pastie>:31: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Seq[A[Trait1]]
 required: Seq[A[Trait2]]
myfunc[Trait2](st1)
           ^
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Type checking is done at compile time but the concrete type of `someField` is not known until run time. All the compiler knows is that it is a sub-class of `ParentTrait`, it cannot know which one will be present when the function is called.

You can either use `match` in `myFunction` to check that you have the type you want, or create two variants of `A` for the two possible types of `someField`.

Unless there is a strong reason for needing static type checking here, I would suggest using `match` and having the unit test framework detect accidental use of the function with the "wrong" value of `someField`. If you go down the variants/generics route then your code is going to get very complicated very quickly.